# NULLが定義されたヘッダファイルを確認するには

Tags: linux, c

stdio.hをincludeした時のNULLの定義を探そうと/usr/include/の下位のファイルをgrep -rしてみたところ

```
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-macros.h:#    define NULL        (0L)
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-macros.h:#    define NULL        ((void*) 0)
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:#  define NULL        (0L)
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:#  define NULL        ((void*) 0)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libio.h:#  define NULL (__null)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libio.h:#   define NULL ((void*)0)
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libio.h:#   define NULL (0)
```

以上が候補として上がってきたのですが。
結果の通り複数あるようで、どのマクロを使っているのかわかりません。

確実に調べる方法をご存知でしたらご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: gcc をお使いでしたら、`gcc -E -dM -x c <(echo '#include <stdio.h>') | grep NULL` とすればよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(g)cc -E ファイル名.c ファイル名.pp`と実行すると、プリプロセッサー処理だけが行われたファイルが`ファイル名.pp`に出力されます。

それを見て、NULLが何に置き換えられているか？で判断出来ませんか？

Comment: ご教示いただいたコマンドですが、私の環境ではファイル名.ppが見当たらないというエラーが出たので。gcc -E ファイル名.cの出力を見ていますが、ここから判断できるハズという認識で正しいでしょうか?

Comment: でしたら、` -E ファイル名.c`で、結果が標準出力に出力されると思います。はい。includeファイルが読み込まれ、マクロが置換された結果が出力されるので、該当箇所が何に置き換わっているか？で判断出来るとおもいます

Comment: gcc -E /usr/include/stdio.hの出力を参照したところ、’define'や'NULL'と言った文字が見つかりませんでしたが、先のgrep -rで出力された候補の中からは、私の認識が正しければ/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libio.hだけが前処理の対象に該当することが確認できました、今回おっしゃりたかった確認の方法はこれで正しいでしょうか?

Comment: はい。先ほどの質問を例に取ると、`gcc -E`で出力された処理後のファイルから `int number = NULL`だった箇所を探し出し、`int number = XXX`のXXXが、今回の質問の何に置き換わっているか？`(0L)`なら、`dbus-macros.h`か`glib/macros.h`だということになりますよね